# ¿Para qué sirve un #! (shebang)?¿Debería escribir también un comentario sobre el programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda en cuanto al uso del "shebang" ¿La primera línea de todos los programas tendría que ser ésta? Por ejemplo:

```
#! python3
# pw.py - Un programa de casilleros de contraseñas.
```

El cual según entiendo le dice a tu ordenador que Python ejecute este programa en el sistema operativo Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Se conoce como `shebang` al conjunto de caracteres `#!` cuando están al principio de la primera o segunda fila de un archivo de texto. Indica que el archivo es un script y  qué intérprete ha de usarse para ejecutarlo. Los sistemas operativos Linux (y otros sistemas Unix-like) soportan de forma nativa esta característica.

> - **#! /usr/bin/python**      -> Usar el ejecutable python localizado en /usr/bin
> - **#! /usr/bin/env python**  -> Usa [env](https://ss64.com/bash/env.html) para buscar la variable de entorno "python" en el PATH para ejecutar el script con ese programa.
> - ...

**Windows no tiene soporte nativo para shebang**, en cambio usa la extensión del archivo para asociarlo al ejecutable de turno. Por lo tanto, la linea de shebang sería completamente ignorada por defecto en el caso de Windows. Eso si, podemos usar por ejemplo [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Para permitir que las líneas shebang en los scripts de Python sean portables entre *nix y Windows, además de otras características, se decidió crear el conocido como [Python Launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), el cual se instala de forma predeterminada con Python >= 3.3 (aunque se puede instalar también de forma independiente si solo tenemos Python 2 instalado).

Esto permite que los archivos `.py` y `.pyw` se asocien a `py.exe` y `pyw.exe` en vez de a un interprete específico. La gracia es que Python Launcher admite una serie de comandos virtuales para especificar qué intérprete usar y que permiten la compatibilidad entre sistemas, las siguientes lineas "shebang" son soportadas:

> - #! python
> - #! /usr/bin/env python
> - #! /usr/bin/python
> - #! /usr/local/bin/python

también permite indicar una ruta real al intérprete como `#!C:/Python37/python.exe`, aunque lógicamente esto no va a ser compatible con otro sistema. En el caso de `#! /usr/bin/env` realiza una búsqueda en el *PATH* similar al trabajo que hace *env* en Linux.

Además, se puede especificar una versión concreta del intérprete a usar mediante sufijo `#! /usr/bin/python2.7`, `#! /usr/bin/python3.7`, etc y se puede usar esta línea para pasar comandos al propio intérprete `#! /usr/bin/python -v`, `#! /usr/bin/python -i`, etc. En función de todo ello *Python Launcher* decide que intérprete usar de los que tiene disponibles.

Aparte de esto, Python Launcher permite lanzar un script con un intérprete determinado o ejecutar su interprete interactivo desde la consola mediante el comando py/pyw:

```
 py -3.6 mi_script.py     # Usar python 3.6
 py -2.7.13 mi_script.py  # Usar python 2.7.13
 py -3 mi_script.py       # Usar versión predeterminada de rama 3
 py -3.7                  # Lanza el intérprete interactivo de Python 3.7
```

...

La segunda línea del script suele usarse de ser necesario para indicar la codificación de caracteres usada en el propio script mediante:

```
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

Python usa UTF-8 en Python 3 y ASCII en Python 2 como codificación para el fichero de código fuente por defecto. Si tenemos un script para Python 2.7 que se a guardado con codificación UTF-8 debemos informar al intérprete de esto mediante la línea:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

la cual debe estar en la primera o segunda línea del módulo. Esto no tiene nada que ver con el SO, es interpretada y usada por el interprete Python.

Ambas lineas no son siempre necesarias ni tienen por que estar siempre presentes. La linea de shebang tiene sentido en un módulo que sea susceptible de ser ejecutado directamente, si es un módulo destinado exclusivamente a ser importado no tiene ninguna funcionalidad.

---

En cuanto a lo del "comentario sobre el programa", generalmente esto debería formar parte de la documentación del módulo, la cual debe estar al principio del mismo (primer estamento, respetando por tanto las dos linea comentadas antes). Se deben usar tres comillas dobles para tal efecto según las convenciones de estilo ([PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
"""Docstring"""
```

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
"""
Multi-line
Docstring
"""
```

Esto permite que por ejemplo se muestre esta información mediante help:

> ```
> >>> import foo
> >>> help(modulo)
>
> Help on module foo:
>
> NAME
>     foo
>
> DESCRIPTION
>     Multi-line
>     Docstring
>
> FILE
>     /home/user/foo.py
> ```