# could not determine name for option @click.option

Tags: python, click

estoy trabajando con click en python click, pero me muestra que no puede determinar la opcion, cosa que realmente estoy asignando

```
import click

import samsara
from samsara.apis import SamsaraClient


@click.command()
@click.option('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', type=str, required=True)
@click.option('490', type=int, required=True)

def get_sensors(access_token, group_id):
    # Create an instance of the SamsaraClient.
    client = SamsaraClient()
    # Get GPS locations for vehicles in the group.
    response = client.get_fleet_locations(access_token,samsara.GroupParam(group_id))

    for vehicle in response.vehicles:
        print ('\nvehicle ID: {}, name: {}, (lat, long): ({}, {}), time:{}'
            .format(vehicle.id, vehicle.name, vehicle.latitude,
                   vehicle.longitude, vehicle.time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_sensors
```

en la opcion donde me marca el error es

```
@click.option('490', type=int, required=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas en tu código:

### Dos tipos de parámetros: opciones y argumentos

Con `@click.option('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', type=str, required=True)` estás definiendo un parámetro opcional, dichos parámetros deben ir precedidos por `-` (short options) o por `--` (long options), por eejemplo `"-h"` y `"--help"`. Si no es una opción sino un parámetro posicional debes usar `click.argument` y no `click.option`.

Tienes una explicación detallada en la documentación oficial del propio `click`:

- https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/parameters/#differences

### Los nombres de los parámetros

**Los nombres de los parámetros son usados como nombre de los argumentos de la función decorada**

`490` no es un identificador válido en Python. Con identificador me refiero a un nombre que puedas asociar a un objeto, es decir el nombre de una variable, clase, función, módulo, etc. Un identificador no puede empezar por un entero:

> ```
> >>> 4foo = [1, 2, 3]
>   File "<stdin>", line 1
>     4foo = [1, 2, 3]
>      ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>> _4foo = [1, 2, 3]
> >>> _123 = "123"
> >>> v123 = "123"
> ```

Debería ser algo así:

```
import click

import samsara
from samsara.apis import SamsaraClient


@click.command()
@click.option('-t', '--access_token', type=str, required=True)
@click.option('-i', '--group_id', type=int, required=True)
def get_sensors(access_token, group_id):
    # Create an instance of the SamsaraClient.
    client = SamsaraClient()
    # Get GPS locations for vehicles in the group.
    response = client.get_fleet_locations(access_token,samsara.GroupParam(group_id))

    for vehicle in response.vehicles:
        print ('\nvehicle ID: {}, name: {}, (lat, long): ({}, {}), time:{}'
            .format(vehicle.id, vehicle.name, vehicle.latitude,
                   vehicle.longitude, vehicle.time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_sensors()
```

El script puede ser llamdo de alguna de éstas formas:

> ```
> $ python script.py --access_token xxxxxxx --group_id 413
> $ python script.py --group_id 413 --access_token xxxxxxx
> $ python script.py --access_token fafafa -i 413
> $ python script.py -i 413 --access_token xxxxxxx
> $ python script.py -t xxxxxxx --group_id 413
> $ python script.py --group_id 413 -t xxxxxxx
> $ python script.py -t xxxxxxx -i 413
> $ python script.py -i 413 -t xxxxxxx
> ```

Otra opción es usar argumentos:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('access_token', type=str)
@click.argument('group_id', type=int)

def get_sensors(access_token, group_id):
    ...
```

En éste caso al script hay que llamarlo así:

> ```
> $ python script.py xxxxxxx 413
> ```

También podrías combinar ambos. Si se [agrega el shebang adecuado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204041/15089) al inicio del script, se puede llamar sin necesidad de anteponer el intérprete a usa.

Comment: Como le pasaria los valores a option?

Comment: Hola @ChristianGtz he editado la respuesta completando con tu duda. Mira a ver que tal. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, ahora lo entendi todo, muchas gracias!!!, muchas gracias por la pasiencia tambien